# How to set Tabview inside the fragment in android

Tags: android

I am new to android.I want to design a page in android which contains a Tab view inside the fragment .

Fragment :

For that I have a Fragment named fragment_home.xml .

Layout Resource files for tabs:

And three layout resource file named

```
today.xml
this-week.xml
this_month.xml
```

and java classes for the resource file is

```
Today.java  
ThisWeek.java 
Thismonth.java
```

What is my doubt is how can I implement the tab view inside the fragment .I have referred some SO files but nothing is helped for me .

Home.java (Fragment):

```
    public class Home extends Fragment{

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private View rootView;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Home() {

    }

    public static Home newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Home fragment = new Home();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Today(), "Today");
        adapter.addFragment(new Reminders(), "Reminders");
        adapter.addFragment(new Settings(), "Settings");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);

            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }






    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Here I want to implement something but I don't know ,How to ?
Please help me to get this.

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.Home">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

PagerAdapter

```
 public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int tabCount;

    public Pager(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int tabCount) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Today todayObj = new Today();
                return todayObj;
            case 1:
                ThisWeek thisWeekObj = new ThisWeek();
                return thisWeekObj;
            case 2:
                ThisMonth thisMonthObj = new ThisMonth();
                return thisMonthObj;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }


    public void addFragment(Today today, String today1) {
    }
    public void addFragment(Reminders reminders, String reminders1) {
    }
    public void addFragment(Settings settings, String settings1) {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You'd do it the same way you would in an `Activity`, except you pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to the `PagerAdapter`, instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class Home extends Fragment{


private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);


    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



return rootView;
}

public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "Fragment name one"); //Need to call first tab fragment 
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), "Fragment name two"); // Need second tab fragment and so on...
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


   public static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);

        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}



}
```

FragmentOne.class

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    return rootView;
    }

}
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@color/plainWhite"
>
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:text="Fragment One Showing"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 android:padding="4dp"
                 android:textSize="18sp"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

FragmentTwo.class

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    return rootView;
    }

}
```

fragment_two.xml

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@color/plainWhite"
>
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:text="Fragment Two Showing"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 android:padding="4dp"
                 android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

use this code , this is the complete example of tablayout using view pager